# Return collection or multidimensional array or array inside array in php

Tags: php, arrays, magento, multidimensional-array, magento-1.9

This question already asked but did not find any good answer.

To retrieve categories and subcategories in magento I am using this function:

```
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
    ->addAttributeToSort('path', 'asc')
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', array('eq'=>'1'))
    ->load()
    ->toArray();

// Arrange categories in required array
$categoryList = array();
foreach ($categories as $catId => $category) {
    if (isset($category['name'])) {
        $categoryList[] = array(
            'label' => $category['name'],
            'level'  =>$category['level'],
            'value' => $catId
        );
    }
}
```

after that if I simply use `return $categoryList;` it will not return anything(just blank) output like:

```
[
    [
    ],
    [
    ],
    [
    ]
]
```

but if  I use `return array(array($categoryList));` in that case it will give right output.

Like this:(checking with json format)

```
[
    [
        [
            {
                "label": "hello",
                "level": "1",
                "value": 2
            },
            {
                "label": "hello1",
                "level": "2",
                "value": 10
            },
            {
                "label": "hello3",
                "level": "3",
                "value": 17
            },
            {
                "label": "Tunics",
                "level": "3",
                "value": 18
            }
       ]
   ]
]
```

but there are two more brackets and I do not want them and as I am new to php I do not have much Idea about how to remove them.

Is there any method which can make it right or I have to create array with different style.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I just ran into the same problem and don't know what to do. Will answer if I find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    $categoryList = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($categories as $catId => $category) {
        if (isset($category['name'])) {
            $categoryList[$i]['label'] = $category['name'];
            $categoryList[$i]['level'] = $category['level'];
            $categoryList[$i]['value'] = $catId;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return json_encode( $categoryList);
```

Output:

```
[{"label":"hello","value":2,"level":"0"},{"label":"hello","value":2,"level":"1"},{"label":"hello","value":2,"level":"2"}]
```

if this doesn't work for you try this

var_dump($categoryList) if it was like this

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          array(3) {
            ["label"]=>
            string(5) "hello"
            ["level"]=>
            string(1) "1"
            ["value"]=>
            int(2)
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

then

```
$response = json_encode($categoryList[0][0][0]);
```

Output:

```
{"label":"hello","level":"1","value":2}
```

Comment: If I use `return json_encode( $categoryList);`  the output come like '[{\"label\":\"hello\",\"level\":\"1\",\"value\":2},{\"label\":\"hello1\",\"level\":\"2\",\"value\":10},{\"label\":\"Tops\",\"level\":\"3\",\"value\":17}]' and this is not acceptable format

Comment: from where these \ (backslash) coming and please share your $categories

Comment: gaurav if I use `echo json_encode( $categoryList);` the output is almost right but in the end getting null see: `[{"label":"hello","level":"1","value":2},{"label":"hello1","level":"2","value":10},{"label":"hello2","level":"3","value":17}]null`

Comment: There must be something else in $categoryList other than your result  
Please share your code and $categories without its hard to tell from the null is coming.

Comment: Actually I am using magento's method to create rest api in this case I am using `function _retrieveCollection` to retrieve category data here if do not use return in the end of function then magento automatically put null value there that is why null is coming. And this is the reason I cannot use echo.

Comment: No problem is still there, I am not able to get data from return in json format(without "\").

Comment: In that case use it if possible
$text = '[{"label":"hello","level":"1","value":2},{"label":"hello1","level":"2","value":10},{"label":"Tops","level":"3","value":17}]';
str_replace('"','"',$text);
output: [{"label":"hello","level":"1","value":2},{"label":"hello1","level":"2","value":10},{"label":"Tops","level":"3","value":17}]
before json_encode

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can use `Mage::log($myvar, Zend_Log::ERR);` to properly display your variable / array. The outpout is in your root directory / var/log/system.log

Then try to log `$categoryList;` and check the format of your response. If you have too much bracket in the result you can use this simple hack :

```
foreach ($categoryList as $category){
    Mage::log($category);
}
```

Hope this help
Cheers